# PowerShell Micro Delay

Tags: powershell, office365, warnings

I'm using `Set-UserPhoto` to update the profile images of hundreds of users in Office 365. After completing roughly 100 updates, I encounter a warning saying `WARNING: Micro delay applied` *(Entire warning below)*. I did some research and although I understand the purpose, meaning, and ramifications of the warning, I do not entirely understand the `Balance:` field.

After one of these warnings, my Balance was listed as `-287463.4/1800000/-3000000`. What do these three numbers mean? I've looked but can't find any detailed reference to this particular warning.

`WARNING: Micro delay applied. Actual delayed: 14704 msecs, Enforced: True, Capped delay: 14704 msecs, Required: False, Additional info: .; PolicyDN: CN
=[BY2PR01MB508]-B2BUpgrade-2014-09-05T18:54:33.9530969Z,CN=Global Settings,CN=Configuration,CN=BASISed.onmicrosoft.com,CN=ConfigurationUnits,DC=NAMPR01
A010,DC=PROD,DC=OUTLOOK,DC=COM; Snapshot: Owner:    Sid~S-1-5-21-723078659-1142018202-613220508-4363960~PowerShell~false
BudgetType: PowerShell
ActiveRunspaces:    0/10
Balance:    -297815.8/1800000/-3000000
PowerShellCmdletsLeft:  400/400
ExchangeCmdletsLeft:    200/200
CmdletTimePeriod:   5
DestructiveCmdletsLeft: 120/120
DestructiveCmdletTimePeriod:    60
QueueDepth: 100
MaxRunspacesTimePeriod: 60
RunSpacesRemaining: 20/20
LastTimeFrameUpdate:    10/24/2018 7:04:49 PM
LastTimeFrameUpdateDestructiveCmdlets:  10/24/2018 7:04:49 PM
LastTimeFrameUpdateMaxRunspaces:    10/24/2018 7:04:49 PM
Locked: False
LockRemaining:  00:00:00`

*Footnote: I've learned I can avoid this warning by entering `Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 30000`, I just want to learn more about the system I'm utilizing.*

Answer (score 2):

The warning is because of the throttling system of O365 to save their resources against big loops with quite resource demanding commands.

I am not sure what first and last number in `Balance` mean but the middle number means `recharge rates`. It tells you how many ms you can spend per hour on consuming resources. In your case its `1 800 000 ms == 30 mins`. The recharge rates depends on your tenant settings and number of mailboxes.

You can read more about O365 throttling policy [here](https://www.quadrotech-it.com/blog/office-365-exchange-online-powershell-throttling/)

However I don't think that you got the micro delay warning because of exceeding the time reserved for your loop/script but you have most likely exceeded any of the limit mentioned in the link above.

More info can be found also [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/exchange/2015/11/02/running-powershell-cmdlets-for-large-numbers-of-users-in-office-365/) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/733sl1/proof_of_concept_avoid_office_365_powershell/)

Comment: Thanks pandemic. I was able to find these links in my own research and they provided some insight but, as I'm sure you found, there isn't much in regards to the first or third numbers.

On the subject of "Recharge Rates", does this mean that the allotted milliseconds per hour recharge at a specified rate per minute? Per hour?

Thanks again.

Comment: According the links the `Recharge rate` means amount of milliseconds per hour. In your case, you can constantly consume resources  30mins per hour. But like I said, i dont think thats the reason why you got a micro delay.